# Rails - Creating a notifications model for Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working to create a notifications model for my users in the app. Which emails they get etc.

I'm going to create a model UserNotifications, with a bunch of columns per setting that are binary.

What I haven't learned yet with Rails is, every user needs to have record in the UserNotifications Model. So how do I do the following:

1. When a user is created, add a record for that user in the UserNotifications table?
2. Handle all the existing user in the DB. When I migrate, how do I tell Rails to build UserNotification records for all the user users in the database?

Thanks for walking me through this. I haven't had to create a model like this before in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing you do in an after_create:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user_notification
  after_create :create_user_notification


  def create_user_notification
    #additional logic probably needed per app requirements
    user_notification.create
  end
end
```

In your migration, you just need to iterate your existing users and call #create_user_notification

Comment: while trying to migrate, I get "undefined method `create_user_notification' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter:0x105edb948>"

Comment: belongs_to vs has_one: I'm assuming the foreign key to the UserNotification is on the user, which in retrospect is probably an invalid assumption.  if the foreign key is on the UserNotification it would be a has_one, with belongs_to on the UserNotification

Comment: for the migration, please edit your question and add the migration definition and relevant portions of your model definition.